# Can not get request body from HttpContext in IAsyncExceptionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my .NET Core 3.1 Web API project, I have a filter that implements `IAsyncExceptionFilter`. In that filter, I'm catching unhandled exceptions, logging them to database along with the incoming HTTP request data(at least I intend to).

My filter looks like this:

```
public class ServiceExceptionInterceptor : IAsyncExceptionFilter
{
    public async Task OnExceptionAsync(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var errorLogService = (IErrorLogService) context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IErrorLogService));

        var req = context.HttpContext.Request;

        var method = req.Method;
        var uri = $"{req.Scheme}://{req.Host}/{req.Path}{req.QueryString}";

        string body = null;

        if (req.ContentLength != null)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(req.Body);
            // body is empty string
            body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }

        var exception = new Models.DB.Exception()
        {
            Type = context.Exception.GetType().ToString(),
            Message = context.Exception.Message,
            StackTrace = context.Exception.StackTrace,
            CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Method = method,
            Uri = uri,
            Body = body
        };

        errorLogService.LogError(exception);

        var error = new Error()
        {
            StatusCode = 500,
            Message = "Something went wrong. There were some technical issues while processing your request."
        };

        context.Result = new JsonResult(error) { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError };
    }
```

In the code above, I check if there is any request body with `req.ContentLength != null`, and it seems like it works fine. When I get a request with no body, `req.ContentLength` is null, and if the request does have a body, it has a value.

But when it comes to getting the content of the request body when there is one, the value I get is always empty string.

As far as I understood from some articles and forum posts, the reason behind this is that the body is read in my controller endpoint, and can not be re-read. I saw a solution that uses the `EnableBuffering()` method in a middleware in `Startup` like below, but it did not work for me.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();
    await next();
});
```

When I remove the `[FromBody]` part from my controller, only then I am able to get the request body.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/questions/{questionId}/comments")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Comment>> AddComment(int questionId, /*[FromBody] AddCommentRequestBody requestBody*/) // -> removing [FromBody] allows the filter to be able to read the request body
{
    throw new Exception("test exception");

    // ...
    // AddComment implementation...
    // ...

    return Ok(addedComment);
}
```

Is there any way to read the request body without removing `[FromBody]` from my controller endpoints?

Comment: Have you tried enabling buffering and resetting the stream position to zero (Body.Position = 0)?

Comment: @NickBailey Adding ```req.Body.Position = 0``` before reading body stream in my filter worked. I also had to keep the middleware where I use ```context.Request.EnableBuffering()``` method. I've tried to reset the stream position before but I guess not in this specific order... Thank you, you can post it as a question if you want :)